Rework Roof Design to add bedrooms

By chance. Does anyone have experience redesigning a roof. In this case, we're trying to see if it is feasible to add two bedrooms in place of the deck.

It appears you have a pyramid style roof.   It also seems like it ties into the lower part of the house.
I also have done upwards and outwards add-ons.   You need a good residential home architect.   There are lots of things to think about and having someone who has done this before draw up plans is crucial.
Unfortunately this isn't as easy as dealing with a normal two sided roof.   A good architect might have a very alternative way but it almost surely will not have the same architectural appeal your current roof has and might have future weak points (think new pyramid roof over new addition).
You need do some measurements and think about the cost/reward trade-off.   It it is feasible to extend the roofline (at same angle, maybe slightly less angle) what would be the height of the exterior walls of the bedroom on the top floor?    If that height is acceptable the lower floor should have no issues and note that based on current architecture - which looks great - the lower room could be quite bigger than the top.
So my general advice and take here is:

If you can extend the roofline for top space and its acceptable the project seems like a worthwhile addition - keep in mind the lower level could be quite a bit larger than the upper level with this roofline.
If you are told you have to cut the roof off... I would buy another house.    Seriously not dealing with the mess of issues this could pose - hvac, electric, plumbing, gas, not to mention ceiling repair...   No way.
I am guessing if you cannot extend the current roof the architect might give you an option for connecting via a perpendicular gable roof.   This could look great and would support having lower and upper addition being equally sized.    I found a good video that goes over this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZROcft3Nbdw.

